# Issue with JPanel as scrollable

Tags: java, swing, applet, jpanel, jscrollpane

I am developing a java JApplet to display few 10s of check boxes in scrollable pane. I included these check boxes in JPanel and added this panel on JScrollPane which is added in current ContentPane of applet. Content pane also has few other components like JTextArea, Button and Label. I would see the scroll bar but when I do scrolling, check boxes are scrolled outside of scrollpane and laid over other adjacent components. I tried setPreferredSize() with no success. What could be the issue with scrolling?

My code bites looks like:

```
public void init(){
contentPane = this.getContentPane(); 
GridBagLayout grrdbag = new GridBagLayout();
GridBagConstraints components = new GridBagConstraints();
contentPane.setLayout(gridbag);
//button, textarea and label components here

//checkboxes here
components = new GridBagConstraints();
components.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
contentPane.add(new Label("Data:", Label.RIGHT), components); 
components = new GridBagConstraints();
components.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
components.weighty = 1;
components.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

checkboxesPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(checkboxesPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
conflictScrollPane = new JScrollPane(checkboxesPanel,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
contentPane.add(conflictScrollPane, components);

}
//create check boxes
public void displayboxes(){
checkboxes = new Checkbox[150];
for(int j=0;j<150;j++){
checkboxes[j] = new Checkbox("This is test data for check box here.",null,false);
checkboxesPanel.add(checkboxes[j]);
checkboxesPanel.revalidate();
}
repaint();
validate();
}
//start method
public void start() {
displayboxes();
repaint();
validate();

}
```

Comment: 1) Please use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.
2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 3) `checkboxes = new Checkbox[150];`  Don't mix Swing components with AWT.

Comment: Also consider [`JTable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).

Answer (score 0):

If your example is to believed, you are mixing heavy weight and light weight components.  My basic recommendation is, don't.  They don't play nice together.

Change your references to Checkbox to JCheckBox instead.

Check out for more info

http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/mixing/

http://java-antony.blogspot.com.au/2007/07/swing-vs-awt-or-lightweight-vs.html

Shane